# File editing with awk or R, change a value if it is a duplicate

Tags: r, bash, awk

I want to edit a file like the following.

file structure, 3 columns

```
 1. 1 xy1 0
 2. 1 xy2 0
 3. 1 xy3 0.04
 4. 1 xy4 0.05
 5. 1 xy5 0.33
 6. 1 xy6 0.33
 7. 1 xy7 0.33
```

if a particular value in column 3 occurs twice or even several times (like "0" in line 1 und 2, and "0.33" in line 5,6 and 7) I want to edit the duplicate values. Everytime a value occured already I want to increase the duplicate value by 0.001. It would look like this:

```
 1. 1 xy1 0
 2. 1 xy2 0.001
 3. 1 xy3 0.04
 4. 1 xy4 0.05
 5. 1 xy5 0.33
 6. 1 xy6 0.331
 7. 1 xy7 0.332
```

The values in line 2, 6 and 7 were increased by 0.001.

How can I do so using either awk/bash or R?
I can identify the duplicates with "cut -f 3 file | sort | uniq -d", but how can I edit a value if it occured already in the list?

I appreciate every hint, thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks a lot to all people replying to my question! Every of the four solutions helped me to solve my problem and additionally better understand awk and R!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ awk '{$3+=(c[$3]++/1000)}1' file
1 xy1 0
1 xy2 0.001
1 xy3 0.04
1 xy4 0.05
1 xy5 0.33
1 xy6 0.331
1 xy7 0.332
```

Comment: Upvoted! Just how simply are you doing it, when people struggled to put an idea over it!

Comment: Brilliant. i am just learning everyday from your answers. not just awk but how to code.. :)

Comment: Any chance you could break this down for a non-awk user? In R I would have done it in a manner similar to rawr's comment `(... +cumsum(duplicated(...)*increment)` which seems somewhat self-documenting but awk code is anything but self-documenting.

Comment: It depends what you're used to, I suppose, but I did favor brevity over clarity for this script as it's so simple (if you know awk, C, or other Algol-based languages). c[$3]++ is an array that's post incremented every time it's hit, so first time any unique $3 is seen, c[$3] is initially zero and then afterwards c[$3] is c[$3]+1. So c[$3]++/1000 is 0 the first time $3 is seen since c[$3]++ is zero, then 1/1000 = 0.001 next time since c[$3]++ is 1, and so on. Then you just add whatever the result of that math is to $3 and reassign the result back to $3 with the `+=` operator, $3+=...

Comment: Thanks for this nice and short solution!

Answer (score 2):

In **R**, supposing your data is in a dataframe, e.g.

```
d <- read.table(text = "
  1 xy1 0
  1 xy2 0
  1 xy3 0.04
  1 xy4 0.05
  1 xy5 0.33
  1 xy6 0.33
  1 xy7 0.33", header = FALSE)
```

We can split the dataframe using the values in column 3, and then add 0.001 sequentially to the values in each subset:

```
d <- do.call(rbind, by(d, d$V3, function(x) {
  x$V3 <- x$V3 + 0.001 * (seq_along(x$V3) - 1)
  x
}))
rownames(d) <- NULL
d
#   V1  V2    V3
# 1  1 xy1 0.000
# 2  1 xy2 0.001
# 3  1 xy3 0.040
# 4  1 xy4 0.050
# 5  1 xy5 0.330
# 6  1 xy6 0.331
# 7  1 xy7 0.332
```

Comment: similar `with(d, ave(V3, V3, FUN = function(x) cumsum(duplicated(x)) * .001 + x))`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{
   if (seen[$3] == "") {
     print $1,$2,$3; seen[$3]=$3
   } else {
     seen[$3] += 0.001; print $1,$2,seen[$3]
   }
}'
```

Note it may use much memory, depending on input file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an R solution.

Suppose `df` is your data frame, then using `while` you can get your desired output.

```
> while(any(duplicated(df$V3))){
    ind <- duplicated(df$V3)
    df$V3[ind] <- df$V3[ind] + 0.001
  }
> 
> df
  V1  V2    V3
1  1 xy1 0.000
2  1 xy2 0.001
3  1 xy3 0.040
4  1 xy4 0.050
5  1 xy5 0.330
6  1 xy6 0.331
7  1 xy7 0.332
```

your original `df` looks like this

```
> df
  V1  V2   V3
1  1 xy1 0.00
2  1 xy2 0.00
3  1 xy3 0.04
4  1 xy4 0.05
5  1 xy5 0.33
6  1 xy6 0.33
7  1 xy7 0.33
```